# What is the GoodData SSO provider name

Tags: gooddata

Anyone can tell me what is the SSO Provider name in GoodData when we send request to their support team to create SSO, In the documentation they say send your SSO Provider Name, What name I need to enter in this place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GoodData SSO Provider name is  identifier for the SSO setup. It can be basically any string, however for better orientation "domain form" related to customer name is strongly preferred.
Examples would be "sso.yourcompany.com" or "pgp.yourcompany.com".
The identifier is than used to set up users for usage of the particular configuration.